Android Studio Emulator error: The emulator process for AVD Pixel_9_API_TiramisuPrivacySandbox has terminated
I faced an error where I was unable to start emulator on android studio. I would face this error The emulator process for AVD Pixel_9_API_TiramisuPrivacySandbox has terminated when starting the emulator. After online research I saw several ways to fix the error but none of them worked for me. It depends for each system on what exactly is the root cause of this error. Please go to Help Tab on your android studio and select "Show Log in Explorer". Select the idea file from that folder and open it. Scroll down to the bottom and check where you can see information related to Emulator failure. In my case I got this error "Emulator terminated with exit code -1073741515". After asking Chat GPT about this specific error, I installed Visual C++ Redistributables from the microsoft website and it fixed my error. I hope this helps others as well.
Fixing the Android Studio Emulator error
